# Exception: divide by zero

Tags: list, haskell

I wanted to find out the list with all powers of 2 that divide 10! it is showing exception i.e. divide by zero

```
[2^i | i<-[1..],(factorial(10) `mod` (2^i))==0]
```

the complete question was to get the function largest_Power such that
largest_Power :: Int -> Int -> Int
largest_Power n p
is the largest power of p that divides n! (factorial of n)

And i tried to make this

```
largest_Power :: Int->Int->Int
largest_Power 0 _ =1  
largest_Power _ 0 =1
largest_Power n p = floor (logBase (fromIntegral p) (fromIntegral (last([p^i | i<-[1..],(factorial(n) `mod` (p^i))==0]))))

factorial::Int->Int
factorial 0=1
factorial 1=1
factorial x=x*factorial(x-1)
```

Now when i ran this for largestPower 10 2 .I am getting exception.

Comment: What is your definition of `factorial`? (For that matter, it's not clear why you are using `factorial` at all, or what your actual question is. Only 1, 2, 4, and 8 have a chance at dividing 10, and only 2 actually does.) If you want the powers of 2 that are divisible by 10, *none* of them are; 10 = 2 * 5, and no power of two is divisible by 5.

Comment: I agree with everything that @chepner said, and wanted to add that if you do fill in a factorial function and run this, there isn't even a divide by zero error....

Comment: the error is most likely because you used `Int` instead of `Integer` to define your `factorial` or you have a `Int` type annotation somewhere

Comment: this should get your list ``let m = product [1..10] in filter (\n -> m `mod` n == 0) $ takeWhile (<= m) [2^i | i <- [1..]]`` - should give you `[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]`

Comment: of course it's quite easy with a bit of math: 10! = 1*2*3*...*10 - and you want to collect all prim-factor 2s in there - it's 2,2*2,2*3,2*2*2,2*5 - so you can take 1 to 8 2`s and that is exactly [2^1,...,2^8] which is the result the script gave you

Comment: (Ugh. Ignore the part of my comment talking about 10; I read the `!` in the first sentence as punctuation, not an operator.)

Comment: sorry everyone ,i am new here so i didn't new about everything .I have updated my question .Now can anyone tell me about the exception  @chepner

Comment: for large enough `i` your `2^i :: Int` will first get negativ then stay at 0 (look at this expression in GHCi: `take 100 $ [2^i | i <- [1..]] :: [Int]`) - as I said you don't want to use `Int` here (try **Integer**) - please look at the snippet I gave above you can easily adapt this without using `log` (which you should not)

Comment: @Carsten i wrote this command `let m = product [1..10] in filter (\n -> m `mod` n == 0) $ takeWhile (<= m) [5^i | i <- [1..],(factorial(10)  `mod`  (5^i))==0]`...and it gives the output as [5,25   i.e.  it is not stopping and last is empty list .Can you please see

Comment: @NiteeshTiwari the hole idea of my little snippet is to move the `filter` away from the list comprehension and you did put it back again - see with this the list comprehension will soon not find another element and there it will *hang* - just use ``let m = product [1..10] in filter (\n -> m `mod` n == 0) $ takeWhile (<= m) [5^i | i <- [1..]]`` - also: the `factorial(10)` is `m` here ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What went wrong with `Int`?

Well `Int` has a bounded range - on most systems `-(2^63)` to `2^63-1`.

Now you start with `1` (which is `1` in binary too) and then add zeroes in binary (which is the same as multiplying by 2) - you always only have one `1` followed by `0`s. At some point you hid the representation of the lower-bound (the highest bit will represent a marker for positive or negative values) and then you will add yet another `0` which will overflow the `Int` end end you with only `0`s.

You can check this easily:

```
Prelude> take 64 $ [2^i | i <- [1..]] :: [Int]
[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,
...
,4611686018427387904,-9223372036854775808,0]
```

That's where the `division by zero` in your original answer came from.

### Why is you list comprehension ending up in bottom

The next problem you have is, that at one point the list-comprehension

```
[2^i | i<-[1..],(factorial(10) `mod` (2^i))==0]
```

will *hang* and not produce any more values.

The reason is simple: for big enough `i`: `2^i > factorial(10)` and will never again divide it.

That's why I would recommend pulling out the filter for the `mod` and first bounding the list to a this hard-limit:

I don't want to write `factorial 10` over and over again so I first define

- `let m = product [1..10]` which is the definition of `factorial 10`
- `[2^i | i <- [1..]]` is a list of *all* numbers in the form `2^i`
- only those smaller `m` are interesting so let's take only those: `takeWhile (<= m) [2^i | i <- [1..]]`
- now the list is finite and it's no problem to use `filter`: `` filter (\n -> m `mod` n == 0) $ takeWhile (<= m) [5^i | i <- [1..]] ``

which yields:

```
λ> let m = product [1..10] 
   in filter (\n -> m `mod` n == 0) 
      $ takeWhile (<= m) 
     [2^i | i <- [1..]]
[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]
```

### solving your problem

of course it turns out that your *problem* was given as:

> the question was to define a function `largest_Power` such that
>   `largest_Power :: Int -> Int -> Int` with `largest_Power n p` is the largest
>   power of `p` that divides `factorial n`

I assume for now that you have to deal with the `Int`s there so you have to springle in some `fromIntegral` to deal with the conversions.

A solution based on your idea and the above snippet could be:

```
largest_Power :: Int -> Int -> Int
largest_Power n p = fromIntegral . last $ factorList n p

factorList :: Int -> Int -> [Integer]
factorList n p =
  filter (\n -> m `mod` n == 0)
  $ takeWhile (<= m) [p'^i | i <- [1..]]
  where m = fromIntegral $ factorial n
        p' = fromIntegral p

factorial :: Int -> Integer
factorial n = product [1..fromIntegral n]
```

---

if you indeed are only interested in the `i` from `p^i` then you can just push this into a tuple and adapt the algorithm a bit:

```
factorList :: Int -> Int -> [Integer]
factorList n p =
  map fst
  . filter (\(_,n) -> m `mod` n == 0)
  $ takeWhile ((<= m) . snd) [(i,p'^i) | i <- [1..]]
  where m = fromIntegral $ factorial n
        p' = fromIntegral p
```

the rest of the program can stay unchanged

### rethinking the algorithm

now if you think about what's going on it honestly doesn't seem to make sense to first create a huge number `factorial n` and then test for divisibility when all we need is the number or times we can divide this number by another (without rest) and when we know that this huge number is just a factor of really small numbers - because the we just can check the smaller numbers and then add up.

So if you are only interested in the `i` from `p^i` again than this will do as well:

```
factorCount :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
factorCount n p =
  let (n',r) = n `divMod` p
  in if r == 0 then 1 + factorCount n' p else 0

largest_Power :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
largest_Power n p = sum [ factorCount i p | i <- [1..n] ]
```

but should be a lot faster for bigger numbers.

Note that you can get this faster still if you memoize the `factorCount` which you probably should if this is an problem for an online contest .. which I suspect ^^

Comment: thank you so much.....You have completely cleared all my doubts